# setOnKeyListener function works on some phones but not on others

Tags: java, android

So i have a function that's supposed to listen for the enter key to be pressed and then hide the keyboard but when i tested it works on one device but not another.

My function:

```
notes.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Works on one phone running Android 8.1 But not on my other phone running Android 8.0

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) says you shouldn't expect software keyboards to trigger this listener.

Comment: Some do and some don't it seems... Both of my test devices use software keyboards... This is just a shortcoming of the Android API i guess.